# Mod - Rewrite / .htaccess Issue with Apache 2.4.12

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache-2.4, apache-1.3

**The file structure is as follows**

- Public files: `/home/usrname/public_html`
- CGI BIN, where the software is running: `/home/usrname/public_html/cgi-bin`
- Private files: `/home/usrname/public_html/_private`
- Databases: `/home/usrname/public_html/_private/data`

What I would like to do is convert the code below from Apache 1.3.42 to an Apache 2.4.12 .htaccess file, seemly a few changes during the SSL path are what I"m really getting hung up on mainly.

When you try any document with the SSL path all I see if the _private path and not the public_html path in the HTML source for any file types, like, CSS, js images, etc.

I also have a permissions issues, which is asking for me to login during SSL mode, this must be due to one of the other `.htaccess` files. It should be simple, yet somehow I'm not getting the rules correctly in-line just yet.

Here are the lines of code in each .htaccess file.

**Public files: /home/usrname/public_html**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^99\.00\.99\.000$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond /home/usrname/public_html/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) /home/usrname/public_html/$1 [L]
RewriteCond /home/usrname/public_html/_private/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) /home/usrname/public_html/_private/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT]

DirectoryIndex home.html index.htm index.html default.htm Default.htm
Action cgi-ccd /cgi-bin/aws.emp
AddHandler cgi-ccd html
AddHandler default-handler .gif
AddHandler default-handler .jpg

<FilesMatch "\.(inx|weo|lco|dbo|cdo|fpo|dao)">
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from env=local_ref
</FilesMatch>

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

We also have these `.htaccess` files on the account in their respective paths.

**Private files: /home/usrname/public_html/_private**

```
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName Administrator
AuthType Basic
<limit GET>
require valid-user
</limit>
```

**Databases: /home/usrname/public_html/_private/data**

```
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName Administrator
AuthType Basic
<limit GET>
require valid-user
</limit>
```

**CGI BIN: /home/usrname/public_html/cgi-bin**

```
Options +ExecCGI
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Perhaps there is something with the way these all work together that are the issue now in Apache 2.4+? Perhaps it's the permissions with calling the file from the CGI-BIN directory, I can move this if needed?

The 301 redirects are fairly simple, seemly. The syntax may need changed for teh version, but they seem simple enough to program. I think there is some conflict with something like Options FollowSymLinks SymLinksIfOwnerMatch ExecCGI Includes MultiViews or some other combination; I have tried several combinations with no luck.

In the end all I'm trying to do mask the full path cgi-bin path of the software, yet provide the old path back as a 301 redirect so we do not lose any links that may be indexed and or bookmarked.

**.i.e.**

```
From: http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/aws.emp/any-document-file-name.html
To: http://www.example.com/any-document-file-name.html
```

**or in SSL mode.**

```
From: https://www.example.com/cgi-bin/aws.emp/any-document-file-name.html
To: https://www.example.com/any-document-file-name.html
```

I found if I change the following from `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` to `%{REQUEST_URI}` that at least allows everything to work, unless you need the SSL path, it then shows the _private path for any file types, such as css, js, images and so on.

I hope I provided enough information to help resolve this pesky issue, sadly I'm very inexperienced with mod_rewrites and thus it seems like somewhat of a black magic right now. This may take weeks to solve simple seemly things on my own.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I so want to migrate off of Apache 1.3.42 as it's way overdue and once this issue has been solved I can.

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever

Comment: Seemly a great link, but I know very little and or even understand mod-rewrites. I'm trying but, time is limited and thus very hard to learn a mountain of information. I guess I have to seke my answers elsewhere. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I found if I change the following from `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` to `%{REQUEST_URI}` that at least allows everything to work

If by this you are referring to the following block of code (supposedly in the root `.htaccess` file):

```
RewriteCond /home/usrname/public_html/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) /home/usrname/public_html/$1 [L]
RewriteCond /home/usrname/public_html/_private/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) /home/usrname/public_html/_private/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT]
```

Then that only makes a little bit of sense. The problem is that these directives wouldn't have worked on Apache 1.3 either, if used in `.htaccess`.

The "problem" is that the contents of that `.htaccess` file looks like it's been taken straight out of the server config. In a `.htaccess` context these directives would never match, regardless of whether `REQUEST_FILENAME` was changed to `REQUEST_URI`. When used in the server config, `REQUEST_FILENAME` is the same as `REQUEST_URI`, but in `.htaccess` `REQUEST_FILENAME` is the absolute filesystem path that the request maps to. So, using `REQUEST_URI` in this context is just "less wrong", it's still not correct.

Rewriting to `/home/usrname/public_html/...` (an absolute filesystem path) is invalid in `.htaccess`. This would result in a 400 Bad Request if successfully executed.

However, these directives don't actually look as if they are doing anything. They simply rewrite the request back to the same file - which doesn't make much sense - so it's difficult to see what the intention of these directives are? Are they perhaps intended to stop other directives from running (eg. to prevent requests being passed to the CGI script)?

> some conflict with something like Options FollowSymLinks SymLinksIfOwnerMatch ExecCGI Includes MultiViews

You'll need `FollowSymLinks` or `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` set for mod_rewrite to function. And you may need to disable `MultiViews`.